# Menu to be displayed as jCarousel

Tags: javascript

Is there a method to show a menu as a jCarousel? My requirement is to show each menu item as element of a jCarousel.

Answer (score 1):

**Short:** If your "menu" was actually a taxonomy tree, it would almost trivial to do what you want, and much more, as most contrib modules operate on a entity basis.

**Longer:** This answer will mostly be applicable to someone that does not already have a menu structure created, so for some people, it will be of little use.

While displaying a Drupal menu in essentially any way is certainly possible, the menu system in Drupal is rather aged compared to a lot of other functionality.

Generally, whenever you wanna do fancy stuff, I would recommend you avoid the menu system completely. You can even disable it completely in D7. Yes, this type of setup will require more work initially, but is *a lot* more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) modules.

Using Views, create a View that lists the titles (or whatever fields you want) of whatever entities you're interested in, and displays them as links. This simulates a menu. Then choose "slideshow" as the display format, and configure to your heart's content.

It won't have hierarchy unless you have grouping fields to use, but a slideshow can't make much use of hierarchy anyway.